# Wordpress Editor iFrame is not loaded

Tags: wordpress, iframe, tinymce, editor

I'm using `wp_editor` in a plugin to let users save some datas.

It's working fine on localhost, but on the website, I keep getting the same problem:
the editor is not themed and pre-text is HTML encoded.

Comparing the two HTML code, I discovered that on the website, what I see is the text area which is hidden in localhost. 
Moreover, the iframe which is loaded in localhost and is supposed to theme and display the editor is not even loaded on the website.

Am I clear?
Any wonderful idea? :)

Comment: looks like the editor has not been initialized in this case (with an editor instance there is an iframe)

Comment: Thanks for answering! What would you suggest? I'm simply using the wp_editor function which works fine in localhost.

Comment: difficult to say. don't you get any javascript errors?

Comment: Not one, and tinymce js loads successfully...

Comment: there needs to be something different. i guess it has something to do with the config.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a conflict between using the Simple Facebook Connect plugin and using the wp_editor function.
Deactivating the plugin made it work, I didn't look further...